# Ruby 1.9.3 and OS X

Tags: ruby, rvm, sass

In bash if I run `ruby -v` it reports I am using `1.9.3p194`.

However, I'm using CodeKit to compile a Compass project, and it keeps returning this error:

```
Compass was unable to compile one or more files in the project: 

LoadError on line 31 of /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb: no such file to load -- toolkit
Run with --trace to see the full backtrace
```

I have CodeKit correctly configured to run Sass 3.2 and Compass 0.13, so I'm not sure why it keeps looking for Ruby in the directory above. Any ideas? I'm also using RVM.

Here are my configuration paths in .bash_profile:

```
PATH="/usr/local/bin:$PATH"
PATH="$PATH:$HOME/bin"
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"
```

and bashrc:

```
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"
```

Comment: @zellio `/Users/me/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/ruby`

Comment: please include your configuration / paths you use in it

Comment: @mpapis I have updated the paths in the question

Comment: what path to `compass` did you set in CodeKit? have you set ruby in any way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using Compass.app over CodeKit. As it stands at the moment, CodeKit just seems to run buggy with Sass 3.2. I'm not running into any issues using Compass.app.